# Solution to error when trying to refresh data in Power BI via schedule

Tags: powerbi

I have a Power BI Pro account, Enterprise Gateway, an uploadet pbix-file, which has a tabular model as data source. The data source has been created in the Gateway and the scheduling options are set up correctly. However, when I do a scheduled OR manual refresh in my browser, I get (freely translated) the following error under update history:

Status: Failed
Error message: This function is not supported. Check that you have installed the latest version of the enterprise gateway

Now, I cannot find a guide to how one updates the gateway, only fresh installs - so that will help, if this is the problem. Otherwise, if anyone has other tips to help me out, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Enterprise Gateway has been deprecated - it is replaced by the "On Premises Data Gateway":

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/gateway/

Comment: Thank you. I will update the gateway and report back if it helps.

Comment: Everything worked as needed once the new gateway was installed.